# Estoy intentando hacer esto Ingresando las nombres y edades de dos personas, determinar cuál es la mayor

Tags: c

Al colocar `printf("%s",n);` no se presenta en la pantalla e intentado colocar `printf("\n\n\t el mayor es ",n);` o `printf("\n\n\t el mayor es %s ",n);`

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
    char n,nn; // n lo uso para colocar los nombres
    int e,ee; // e lo uso para edades
    printf("\n\n\n\t\t Ingresar su nombre y su edad");
    printf("\n\n\n\t\t Ingrese nombre 1: ");
    scanf("%s",&n);
    printf("\n\n\n\t\t Ingrese su edad: ");
    scanf("%d",&e);
    printf("\n\n\n\t\t Ingrese nombre 2: ");
    scanf("%s",&nn);
    printf("\n\n\n\t\t Ingrese su edad: ");
    scanf("%d",&ee);
    if (e>ee);
    {
    printf("\n\n\t\t El mayor es ");
    printf("%s",n); // lo uso para identificarlo por el nombre y no por las edades
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que el sistema no alcanza a imprimir el texto antes de que se pida la entrada. Hay que usar la función `fflush()` para forzar a que el texto se imprima. Además de eso, hay que declarar `n` y `nn` como arreglos de `char`, no como carácteres:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char n[100],nn[100]; // n lo uso para colocar los nombres
    int e,ee; // e lo uso para edades
    printf("\n\n\n\t\t Ingresar su nombre y su edad");
    printf("\n\n\n\t\t Ingrese nombre 1: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%s",&n);
    printf("\n\n\n\t\t Ingrese su edad: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%d",&e);
    printf("\n\n\n\t\t Ingrese nombre 2: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%s",&nn);
    printf("\n\n\n\t\t Ingrese su edad: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%d",&ee);
    if (e>ee);
    {
        printf("\n\n\t\t El mayor es ");
        printf("%s",n); // lo uso para identificarlo por el nombre y no por las edades
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Saludos.

Comment: He comenzado con c estos dias y vi que tambien se declara *n sin especificar cantidad. Es mas eficiente que n[100]? Porque en el puntero no se declara cantidad cierto?

Comment: De la forma en la que lo estas haciendo tu, vas a sobreescribir el buffer (ya que solo le das 1 de espacio, y vas a leer varios caracteres). Si lo colocas como solo un puntero vas a parar escribiendo a memoria que no has asignado, ya que no sabes a donde apunta el puntero. La forma correcta es como la esta haciendo patricio. @HernánGarcia